# Convert a simple text column date to a date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting

I need to convert this type of a `nvarchar` column to a date. The data in the column `F2` looks like this: `09222018`.

I want to convert to a date and have it look like `09/22/2018`.

I've tried this, and get incorrect syntax.

```
SELECT
    f2,
    CAST(f2, AS datetime)
FROM 
    Testbk
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT
    f2,
    CONVERT(nvarchar, f2, 101)
FROM 
    Testbk
```

Again - no successful conversion.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? You're trying to use product specific functionality.

Comment: Remove the comma, do `cast(f2 as datetime)`,

Comment: MS SQL Server  and when i remove the comma and use cast(f2 as datetime)  i get   Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Personally I don't like the format you're trying to return (mm/dd/yyyy). IMHO, this would be a better format and a way to accomplish what you are wanting... `CONVERT(DATE,CONCAT(RIGHT(f2,4),LEFT(f2,4)),112)`

Comment: Convert that to a date fine, but leave the formatting to the front end.

Comment: The real question is why are you storing your date (and the) data as a string based data type? There are date and time data types for a reason; fix your design, that is the real solution.

Comment: The reason your second attempt, when you tried to `CONVERT` the value to an `nvarchar` with a style code, didn't work is because the value is *already* an `nvarchar`. Converting an `nvarchar` to an `nvarchar` will do *nothing*; the style code is only used when converting to/from a string based data type to a non-string based data type.

Comment: i used this, CONVERT(DATE,CONCAT(RIGHT(f2,4),LEFT(f2,4)),112) and it works but when i put 101 to get mm/dd/yyyy it doesnt convert it to the date format i need.  it says at yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, what you *really* need to do here is fix your design. It appears here that your column represents a date in the format `MMddyyyy`, as a result we need to change your column to a `date` data type.

To get your column to be the right data type we'll doing to need to get it into an unambiguous format, ideally `yyyyMMdd`. To do this we'll need to `CONVERT` it to a `date` and then *back* to a string based value in the unambiguous format. Then we can `ALTER` the column to the correct data type.

Unfortunately there isn't a [style code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) for `MMddyyyy` but there is for `MM/dd/yyyy`: `101`. Changing your value to this isn't too difficult, just a couple of `STUFF`s. Then  we can use `TRY_CONVERT` to attempt to convert the value to a `date` (if it isn't a valid date, the value will be lost) and then we can `CONVERT` that back to a `varchar`.

I start by adding a *new* column though, as this will store the original values, which you can inspect to *try* to recover any bad data.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Testbk ADD StringDate varchar(8); --length assumes all MMddyyyy

UPDATE dbo.Testbk
SET StringDate = f2;
GO

UPDATE dbo.Testbk
SET f2 = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(f2,5,0,'/'),3,0,'/'),101),112);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Testbk ALTER COLUMN f2 date /*NOT NULL*/;
```

Now your design is fixed you can then worry about what the value is *presented* like in your *presentation* layer, as your application will receive the * binary* value of the date value and be able to properly format that however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure, what you want to achieve: convert value to a date or dislay it in another format.
Please see below

```
declare @InF2 varchar(8)='09222018';
select @InF2,LEFT(@iNf2,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@InF2,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@InF2,5,4)AS VARCHAR_USA_DATE,
CONVERT(DATE,LEFT(@iNf2,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@InF2,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@InF2,5,4),101)AS DATE_converted
```

Comment: that works.  i have column that has 70k plus records in the format similar to 09222018 and want that converted to a date field.

Comment: it returns about 15k rows but i get this error.   Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Completion time: 2023-08-28T13:20:58.3685497-05:00 

is that because there is a bad data in that field somewhere?

Comment: most probably. You can take look on TRY_CONVERT-function to find this suspicious data

Comment: how would i do that for this field?  sorry ive never used try-convert function before.

Comment: select try_convert(date,LEFT(f2,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(F2,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(F2,5,4),101) from your_table
where try_convert(date,LEFT(f2,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(F2,3,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(F2,5,4),101) is null

Comment: when i use this format in a view.  why does my view column still showing as nvarchar.  my issue is the program we are using needs a date format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```sql
Select   convert(varchar(10),cast(STUFF(STUFF(f2, 3,0,'/'),6,0,'/')as
datetime),101)as f2 from Testbk
```

Have a look here: https://dbfiddle.uk/VUDoJYl8

Comment: Why `varchar(50)` when the output is known to be 10 characters??

Comment: @Stu Yes, I got your point. Was trying few things on db fiddle before posting answer here. But forgot to correct the length.  am editing the answer as per your notification. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

More than one way to do this, try to separate conversion from the format of the output - even if they are in one query. I used some syntax compatible with older SQL perhaps since a version was not specified.

One sample:

```
DECLARE @D NVARCHAR(8) = '09222018';
DECLARE @DT DATETIME;

SELECT SUBSTRING(@D, 5, 4),  SUBSTRING(@D, 3, 2),SUBSTRING(@D,1, 2);

SELECT @DT = CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@D, 5, 4),'-', SUBSTRING(@D, 1, 2) ,'-', SUBSTRING(@D,3, 2)) AS DATETIME);

SELECT FORMAT(@DT,'MM-dd-yyyy');
```